# SQL Query to Update the Start and End Date in a table from a different column where the dates do not match

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Part       | Quantity|Mapping                                                                                                                                                                                  |First_Date|Las_Date
6684MC6906 |    1    |-> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-25-NOV-15-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-12-SEP-17-20-SEP-21 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-07-JUN-17-20-OCT-21 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-06-APR-12-15-AUG-22|          |
6684MC6906 |    1    |-> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-25-NOV-15-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-20-SEP-21-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-JUN-21-20-OCT-21 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-06-APR-12-15-AUG-22|          |
```

I need a query which will Update the Start_Date and End_Date in this table. By Checking the Mapping column.When the value of date starts to change that should become the new start and end date.

For example :

```
Record_1 -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-25-NOV-15-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-12-SEP-17-20-SEP-21 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-07-JUN-17-20-OCT-21 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-06-APR-12-15-AUG-22

Record_2  -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-25-NOV-15-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-20-SEP-21-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-JUN-21-20-OCT-21 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-06-APR-12-15-AUG-22.
```

The above two are same till the part `25-NOV-15-15-AUG-22`.
So our new Start_date for 1st record should be =`12-SEP-17` and End_date should be =`20-SEP-21`.
For second record Start_date =`20-SEP-21` and `15-AUG-22`.

Please let me know if any clarification needed. I'll try my best to explain.

Below are the table scripts and insert statements.

```
create table bom_duplicates
(
LVL NUMBER,
TOP_PART    VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID    NUMBER,
FLAT_COMPONENT  VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
COMPONENT_ID    NUMBER,
ORGANIZATION_ID NUMBER,
USAGE_QUANTITY  NUMBER,
PLANNING_FACTOR NUMBER,
TRUE_TOP_PART   VARCHAR2(300 BYTE),
PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
TYPE_PATH   VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
PATH_START_DATE VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
ORGANIZATION_CODE   VARCHAR2(180 BYTE),
PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE    VARCHAR2(40 BYTE),
CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE VARCHAR2(40 BYTE),
START_DATE  DATE,
END_DATE    DATE,
ITEM_TYPE   VARCHAR2(90 BYTE),
PARENT_ITEM_TYPE    VARCHAR2(90 BYTE)
);

Insert into BOM_DUPLICATES (LVL,TOP_PART,ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID,FLAT_COMPONENT,COMPONENT_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USAGE_QUANTITY,PLANNING_FACTOR,TRUE_TOP_PART,PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY,TYPE_PATH,PATH_START_DATE,ORGANIZATION_CODE,PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE,CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE,ITEM_TYPE,PARENT_ITEM_TYPE) values (4,'445-0773300',127180,'007-9714401',17644,10007,6,100,'6684MC6906','*1*1*1*6',' -> CID -> FEATURE -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY',' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-25-NOV-15-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22','BUD','Make','Buy',to_date('22-NOV-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'FSD BUY RAW MAT','FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY');
Insert into BOM_DUPLICATES (LVL,TOP_PART,ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID,FLAT_COMPONENT,COMPONENT_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USAGE_QUANTITY,PLANNING_FACTOR,TRUE_TOP_PART,PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY,TYPE_PATH,PATH_START_DATE,ORGANIZATION_CODE,PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE,CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE,ITEM_TYPE,PARENT_ITEM_TYPE) values (4,'445-0773300',127180,'007-9714401',17644,10007,6,100,'6684MC6906','*1*1*1*6',' -> CID -> FEATURE -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY',' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-27-JUN-16-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22','BUD','Make','Buy',to_date('22-NOV-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'FSD BUY RAW MAT','FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY');
Insert into BOM_DUPLICATES (LVL,TOP_PART,ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID,FLAT_COMPONENT,COMPONENT_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USAGE_QUANTITY,PLANNING_FACTOR,TRUE_TOP_PART,PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY,TYPE_PATH,PATH_START_DATE,ORGANIZATION_CODE,PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE,CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE,ITEM_TYPE,PARENT_ITEM_TYPE) values (4,'445-0773300',127180,'009-0006590',18027,10007,14,100,'6684MC6906','*1*1*1*14',' -> CID -> FEATURE -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY',' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-25-NOV-15-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22','BUD','Make','Buy',to_date('22-NOV-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'FSD BUY RAW MAT','FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY');
Insert into BOM_DUPLICATES (LVL,TOP_PART,ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID,FLAT_COMPONENT,COMPONENT_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USAGE_QUANTITY,PLANNING_FACTOR,TRUE_TOP_PART,PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY,TYPE_PATH,PATH_START_DATE,ORGANIZATION_CODE,PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE,CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE,ITEM_TYPE,PARENT_ITEM_TYPE) values (4,'445-0773300',127180,'009-0006590',18027,10007,14,100,'6684MC6906','*1*1*1*14',' -> CID -> FEATURE -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY',' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-27-JUN-16-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22','BUD','Make','Buy',to_date('22-NOV-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'FSD BUY RAW MAT','FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY');
Insert into BOM_DUPLICATES (LVL,TOP_PART,ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID,FLAT_COMPONENT,COMPONENT_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USAGE_QUANTITY,PLANNING_FACTOR,TRUE_TOP_PART,PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY,TYPE_PATH,PATH_START_DATE,ORGANIZATION_CODE,PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE,CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE,ITEM_TYPE,PARENT_ITEM_TYPE) values (4,'445-0773300',127180,'009-0006591',18028,10007,4,100,'6684MC6906','*1*1*1*4',' -> CID -> FEATURE -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY',' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-25-NOV-15-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22','BUD','Make','Buy',to_date('22-NOV-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'FSD BUY RAW MAT','FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY');
Insert into BOM_DUPLICATES (LVL,TOP_PART,ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID,FLAT_COMPONENT,COMPONENT_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USAGE_QUANTITY,PLANNING_FACTOR,TRUE_TOP_PART,PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY,TYPE_PATH,PATH_START_DATE,ORGANIZATION_CODE,PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE,CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE,ITEM_TYPE,PARENT_ITEM_TYPE) values (4,'445-0773300',127180,'009-0006591',18028,10007,4,100,'6684MC6906','*1*1*1*4',' -> CID -> FEATURE -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY',' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-27-JUN-16-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22','BUD','Make','Buy',to_date('22-NOV-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'FSD BUY RAW MAT','FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY');
Insert into BOM_DUPLICATES (LVL,TOP_PART,ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID,FLAT_COMPONENT,COMPONENT_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USAGE_QUANTITY,PLANNING_FACTOR,TRUE_TOP_PART,PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY,TYPE_PATH,PATH_START_DATE,ORGANIZATION_CODE,PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE,CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE,ITEM_TYPE,PARENT_ITEM_TYPE) values (4,'445-0773300',127180,'009-0030192',22158,10007,2,100,'6684MC6906','*1*1*1*2',' -> CID -> FEATURE -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY',' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-25-NOV-15-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22','BUD','Make','Buy',to_date('22-NOV-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'FSD BUY RAW MAT','FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY');
Insert into BOM_DUPLICATES (LVL,TOP_PART,ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID,FLAT_COMPONENT,COMPONENT_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USAGE_QUANTITY,PLANNING_FACTOR,TRUE_TOP_PART,PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY,TYPE_PATH,PATH_START_DATE,ORGANIZATION_CODE,PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE,CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE,ITEM_TYPE,PARENT_ITEM_TYPE) values (4,'445-0773300',127180,'009-0030192',22158,10007,2,100,'6684MC6906','*1*1*1*2',' -> CID -> FEATURE -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY',' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-27-JUN-16-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22','BUD','Make','Buy',to_date('22-NOV-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'FSD BUY RAW MAT','FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY');
Insert into BOM_DUPLICATES (LVL,TOP_PART,ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID,FLAT_COMPONENT,COMPONENT_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USAGE_QUANTITY,PLANNING_FACTOR,TRUE_TOP_PART,PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY,TYPE_PATH,PATH_START_DATE,ORGANIZATION_CODE,PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE,CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE,ITEM_TYPE,PARENT_ITEM_TYPE) values (4,'445-0773300',127180,'445-0754353',116356,10007,1,100,'6684MC6906','*1*1*1*1',' -> CID -> FEATURE -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY',' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-25-NOV-15-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22','BUD','Make','Buy',to_date('22-NOV-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'FSD BUY RAW MAT','FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY');
Insert into BOM_DUPLICATES (LVL,TOP_PART,ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID,FLAT_COMPONENT,COMPONENT_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USAGE_QUANTITY,PLANNING_FACTOR,TRUE_TOP_PART,PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY,TYPE_PATH,PATH_START_DATE,ORGANIZATION_CODE,PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE,CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE,ITEM_TYPE,PARENT_ITEM_TYPE) values (4,'445-0773300',127180,'445-0754353',116356,10007,1,100,'6684MC6906','*1*1*1*1',' -> CID -> FEATURE -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY',' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-27-JUN-16-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22','BUD','Make','Buy',to_date('22-NOV-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'FSD BUY RAW MAT','FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY');
Insert into BOM_DUPLICATES (LVL,TOP_PART,ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID,FLAT_COMPONENT,COMPONENT_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USAGE_QUANTITY,PLANNING_FACTOR,TRUE_TOP_PART,PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY,TYPE_PATH,PATH_START_DATE,ORGANIZATION_CODE,PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE,CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE,ITEM_TYPE,PARENT_ITEM_TYPE) values (4,'445-0773300',127180,'445-0754507',116441,10007,2,100,'6684MC6906','*1*1*1*2',' -> CID -> FEATURE -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY',' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-25-NOV-15-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22','BUD','Make','Buy',to_date('22-NOV-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'FSD BUY RAW MAT','FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY');
Insert into BOM_DUPLICATES (LVL,TOP_PART,ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID,FLAT_COMPONENT,COMPONENT_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USAGE_QUANTITY,PLANNING_FACTOR,TRUE_TOP_PART,PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY,TYPE_PATH,PATH_START_DATE,ORGANIZATION_CODE,PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE,CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE,ITEM_TYPE,PARENT_ITEM_TYPE) values (4,'445-0773300',127180,'445-0754507',116441,10007,2,100,'6684MC6906','*1*1*1*2',' -> CID -> FEATURE -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY',' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-27-JUN-16-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22','BUD','Make','Buy',to_date('22-NOV-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'FSD BUY RAW MAT','FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY');
Insert into BOM_DUPLICATES (LVL,TOP_PART,ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID,FLAT_COMPONENT,COMPONENT_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USAGE_QUANTITY,PLANNING_FACTOR,TRUE_TOP_PART,PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY,TYPE_PATH,PATH_START_DATE,ORGANIZATION_CODE,PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE,CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE,ITEM_TYPE,PARENT_ITEM_TYPE) values (4,'445-0773300',127180,'445-0754508',116442,10007,2,100,'6684MC6906','*1*1*1*2',' -> CID -> FEATURE -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY',' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-25-NOV-15-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22','BUD','Make','Buy',to_date('22-NOV-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'FSD BUY RAW MAT','FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY');
Insert into BOM_DUPLICATES (LVL,TOP_PART,ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID,FLAT_COMPONENT,COMPONENT_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USAGE_QUANTITY,PLANNING_FACTOR,TRUE_TOP_PART,PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY,TYPE_PATH,PATH_START_DATE,ORGANIZATION_CODE,PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE,CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE,ITEM_TYPE,PARENT_ITEM_TYPE) values (4,'445-0773300',127180,'445-0754508',116442,10007,2,100,'6684MC6906','*1*1*1*2',' -> CID -> FEATURE -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY',' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-27-JUN-16-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22','BUD','Make','Buy',to_date('22-NOV-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'FSD BUY RAW MAT','FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY');
Insert into BOM_DUPLICATES (LVL,TOP_PART,ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID,FLAT_COMPONENT,COMPONENT_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USAGE_QUANTITY,PLANNING_FACTOR,TRUE_TOP_PART,PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY,TYPE_PATH,PATH_START_DATE,ORGANIZATION_CODE,PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE,CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE,ITEM_TYPE,PARENT_ITEM_TYPE) values (4,'445-0773300',127180,'445-0754509',116443,10007,1,100,'6684MC6906','*1*1*1*1',' -> CID -> FEATURE -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY',' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-25-NOV-15-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22','BUD','Make','Buy',to_date('22-NOV-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'FSD BUY RAW MAT','FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY');
Insert into BOM_DUPLICATES (LVL,TOP_PART,ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID,FLAT_COMPONENT,COMPONENT_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USAGE_QUANTITY,PLANNING_FACTOR,TRUE_TOP_PART,PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY,TYPE_PATH,PATH_START_DATE,ORGANIZATION_CODE,PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE,CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE,ITEM_TYPE,PARENT_ITEM_TYPE) values (4,'445-0773300',127180,'445-0754509',116443,10007,1,100,'6684MC6906','*1*1*1*1',' -> CID -> FEATURE -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY',' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-27-JUN-16-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22','BUD','Make','Buy',to_date('22-NOV-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'FSD BUY RAW MAT','FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY');
Insert into BOM_DUPLICATES (LVL,TOP_PART,ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID,FLAT_COMPONENT,COMPONENT_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USAGE_QUANTITY,PLANNING_FACTOR,TRUE_TOP_PART,PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY,TYPE_PATH,PATH_START_DATE,ORGANIZATION_CODE,PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE,CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE,ITEM_TYPE,PARENT_ITEM_TYPE) values (4,'445-0773300',127180,'445-0761622',122703,10007,1,100,'6684MC6906','*1*1*1*1',' -> CID -> FEATURE -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY',' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-25-NOV-15-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22','BUD','Make','Buy',to_date('22-NOV-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'FSD BUY RAW MAT','FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY');
Insert into BOM_DUPLICATES (LVL,TOP_PART,ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID,FLAT_COMPONENT,COMPONENT_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USAGE_QUANTITY,PLANNING_FACTOR,TRUE_TOP_PART,PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY,TYPE_PATH,PATH_START_DATE,ORGANIZATION_CODE,PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE,CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE,ITEM_TYPE,PARENT_ITEM_TYPE) values (4,'445-0773300',127180,'445-0761622',122703,10007,1,100,'6684MC6906','*1*1*1*1',' -> CID -> FEATURE -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY',' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-27-JUN-16-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22','BUD','Make','Buy',to_date('22-NOV-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'FSD BUY RAW MAT','FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY');
Insert into BOM_DUPLICATES (LVL,TOP_PART,ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID,FLAT_COMPONENT,COMPONENT_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USAGE_QUANTITY,PLANNING_FACTOR,TRUE_TOP_PART,PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY,TYPE_PATH,PATH_START_DATE,ORGANIZATION_CODE,PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE,CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE,ITEM_TYPE,PARENT_ITEM_TYPE) values (4,'445-0773300',127180,'445-0763050',123517,10007,1,100,'6684MC6906','*1*1*1*1',' -> CID -> FEATURE -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY',' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-25-NOV-15-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22','BUD','Make','Buy',to_date('22-NOV-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'FSD BUY RAW MAT','FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY');
Insert into BOM_DUPLICATES (LVL,TOP_PART,ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID,FLAT_COMPONENT,COMPONENT_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USAGE_QUANTITY,PLANNING_FACTOR,TRUE_TOP_PART,PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY,TYPE_PATH,PATH_START_DATE,ORGANIZATION_CODE,PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE,CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE,ITEM_TYPE,PARENT_ITEM_TYPE) values (4,'445-0773300',127180,'445-0763050',123517,10007,1,100,'6684MC6906','*1*1*1*1',' -> CID -> FEATURE -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY',' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-27-JUN-16-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22','BUD','Make','Buy',to_date('22-NOV-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'FSD BUY RAW MAT','FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY');
Insert into BOM_DUPLICATES (LVL,TOP_PART,ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID,FLAT_COMPONENT,COMPONENT_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USAGE_QUANTITY,PLANNING_FACTOR,TRUE_TOP_PART,PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY,TYPE_PATH,PATH_START_DATE,ORGANIZATION_CODE,PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE,CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE,ITEM_TYPE,PARENT_ITEM_TYPE) values (4,'445-0773300',127180,'445-0763319',123628,10007,1,100,'6684MC6906','*1*1*1*1',' -> CID -> FEATURE -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY',' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-25-NOV-15-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22','BUD','Make','Buy',to_date('22-NOV-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'FSD BUY RAW MAT','FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY');
Insert into BOM_DUPLICATES (LVL,TOP_PART,ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID,FLAT_COMPONENT,COMPONENT_ID,ORGANIZATION_ID,USAGE_QUANTITY,PLANNING_FACTOR,TRUE_TOP_PART,PATH_USAGE_QUANTITY,TYPE_PATH,PATH_START_DATE,ORGANIZATION_CODE,PARENT_MAKE_BUY_CODE,CHILD_MAKE_BUY_CODE,START_DATE,END_DATE,ITEM_TYPE,PARENT_ITEM_TYPE) values (4,'445-0773300',127180,'445-0763319',123628,10007,1,100,'6684MC6906','*1*1*1*1',' -> CID -> FEATURE -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY',' -> CID-29-JAN-21-15-AUG-22 -> FEATURE-27-JUN-16-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-22-NOV-18-15-AUG-22 -> FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY-13-NOV-18-15-AUG-22','BUD','Make','Buy',to_date('22-NOV-18','DD-MON-RR'),to_date('15-AUG-22','DD-MON-RR'),'FSD BUY RAW MAT','FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY');
```

Comment: Do all mappings always start with CID and FEATURE?

Comment: No this can be different @Gnqz

Comment: By change in dates you mean change in the second part (15-AUG-22)?

Comment: Yes after this (15-AUG-22) the next date in both records is changed . So for 1st record First _Date =12-SEP-17 and end_date =20-SEP-21. and for the second record First _Date =20-SEP-21 and end_date =15-AUG-22

Comment: @MT0 The query is not working for me it is updating both the columns as null

Comment: @GauravThuckral Please [edit] your question to give a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for your table; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data. Just saying "the query is not working" is not constructive as it does not say why it is not working so it gives me nothing to work with when debugging; as you can see from my answer, it does work so you need to do some debugging to try to work out what the difference is between the sample data you gave in the question and the data you are running it on and then give some more constructive feedback.

Comment: @MTO this works for two records in the table but we need to write a query which is generic and updates all the records in the table.

Comment: @MTO i have added the script and insert statements. Could you please try now.

Comment: @MT0 can you have a look ?

Comment: @MT0 I have a more simple scenario now. I just want to make the min of the date as First date and Max of the End date as the end date. But there is one condition we have to select dates after "FSD PHANTOM SUBASSY". Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: Also we need not compare multiple records now. we just have to write a simple update across the whole table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
MERGE INTO bom_duplicates dst
USING (
  WITH numbered_parts (rid, component_id, path_start_date, rn) AS ( 
    SELECT rowid,
           component_id,
           path_start_date,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY component_id ORDER BY rowid)
    FROM   bom_duplicates
  ),
  matched_parts (rid1, rid2, path_start_date1, path_start_date2) AS (
    SELECT p1.rid,
           p2.rid,
           p1.path_start_date,
           p2.path_start_date
    FROM   numbered_parts p1
           INNER JOIN numbered_parts p2
           ON (p1.component_id = p2.component_id)
    WHERE  p1.rn = 1
    AND    p2.rn = 2
  ),
  paths (rid1, rid2, path_start_date1, path_start_date2, idx, path1, path2, num_paths) AS (
    SELECT rid1,
           rid2,
           path_start_date1,
           path_start_date2,
           2,
           REGEXP_SUBSTR(path_start_date1, '[^>]+', 1, 2),
           REGEXP_SUBSTR(path_start_date2, '[^>]+', 1, 2),
           GREATEST(
             REGEXP_COUNT(path_start_date1, '[^>]+'),
             REGEXP_COUNT(path_start_date2, '[^>]+')
           )
    FROM   matched_parts
  UNION ALL
    SELECT rid1,
           rid2,
           path_start_date1,
           path_start_date2,
           idx + 1,
           REGEXP_SUBSTR(path_start_date1, '[^>]+', 1, idx + 1),
           REGEXP_SUBSTR(path_start_date2, '[^>]+', 1, idx + 1),
           num_paths
    FROM   paths
    WHERE  idx < num_paths
    AND    path1 = path2
  ),
  changed_dates (rid1, rid2, start_date1, end_date1, start_date2, end_date2) AS (
    SELECT rid1,
           rid2,
           TO_DATE(
             REGEXP_SUBSTR(
               path1,
               '(\d{2}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{2})-(\d{2}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{2})',
               1,
               1,
               NULL,
               1
             ),
             'DD-MON-RR'
           ) AS start_date1,
           TO_DATE(
             REGEXP_SUBSTR(
               path1,
               '(\d{2}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{2})-(\d{2}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{2})',
               1,
               1,
               NULL,
               2
             ),
             'DD-MON-RR'
           ) AS end_date1,
           TO_DATE(
             REGEXP_SUBSTR(
               path2,
               '(\d{2}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{2})-(\d{2}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{2})',
               1,
               1,
               NULL,
               1
             ),
             'DD-MON-RR'
           ) AS start_date2,
           TO_DATE(
             REGEXP_SUBSTR(
               path2,
               '(\d{2}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{2})-(\d{2}-[A-Z]{3}-\d{2})',
               1,
               1,
               NULL,
               2
             ),
             'DD-MON-RR'
           ) AS end_date2
    FROM   paths
    WHERE  path1 <> path2
  )
  SELECT rid,
         start_date,
         end_date
  FROM   changed_dates
  UNPIVOT (
    (rid, start_date, end_date)
    FOR type IN (
      (rid1, start_date1, end_date1) AS 1,
      (rid2, start_date2, end_date2) AS 2
    )
  )
) src
ON (dst.ROWID = src.rid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET start_date = src.start_date,
      end_date  = src.end_date;
```

Which, for your sample data, then:

```sql
SELECT component_id, start_date, end_date FROM bom_duplicates;
```

Outputs:

> | COMPONENT_ID | START_DATE | END_DATE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 17644 | 25-NOV-15 | 15-AUG-22 |
> | 17644 | 27-JUN-16 | 15-AUG-22 |
> | 18027 | 25-NOV-15 | 15-AUG-22 |
> | 18027 | 27-JUN-16 | 15-AUG-22 |
> | 18028 | 25-NOV-15 | 15-AUG-22 |
> | 18028 | 27-JUN-16 | 15-AUG-22 |
> | 22158 | 25-NOV-15 | 15-AUG-22 |
> | 22158 | 27-JUN-16 | 15-AUG-22 |
> | 116356 | 25-NOV-15 | 15-AUG-22 |
> | 116356 | 27-JUN-16 | 15-AUG-22 |
> | 116441 | 25-NOV-15 | 15-AUG-22 |
> | 116441 | 27-JUN-16 | 15-AUG-22 |
> | 116442 | 25-NOV-15 | 15-AUG-22 |
> | 116442 | 27-JUN-16 | 15-AUG-22 |
> | 116443 | 25-NOV-15 | 15-AUG-22 |
> | 116443 | 27-JUN-16 | 15-AUG-22 |
> | 122703 | 25-NOV-15 | 15-AUG-22 |
> | 122703 | 27-JUN-16 | 15-AUG-22 |
> | 123517 | 25-NOV-15 | 15-AUG-22 |
> | 123517 | 27-JUN-16 | 15-AUG-22 |
> | 123628 | 25-NOV-15 | 15-AUG-22 |
> | 123628 | 27-JUN-16 | 15-AUG-22 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4c1fcf9b4a957d02f1a2f9e464ffdf81)*